# Is it possible to study Differential Geometry from Spivak's books starting with the second volume without reading the first one?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, reference-works

**Is it possible to study *Differential Geometry* from Spivak's books starting with the second volume without reading the first one ?**

The content of Differential Geometry course that is taught in the university that I'm attending contains only the topics that are in the second volume of Spivak's books, without providing anything related with the topics in the first volume, and I was going to study the subject before taking this course, so this led me to this question.

Comment: Bad idea to skip.

Comment: Yes you can. I did

Comment: @Dac0 Thanks for your comment Dac0, but the fact that you have "done" it does not imply that it is a good idea. My question in here is that how crucial the material in the first book for the material in the second book.

Comment: It is not a good idea but it can be done. The best idea to study differential Geometry is doing a huge amount of exercises. And believe me it's the only way. As for the text Spivak is good